# How to add a label below sequencediagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I haven't found a way to add a label (like in images) below a sequencediagram. Is it possible? I want to make references to diagrams in my text but I dont know how to display a label for each sequencediagram. TIA

For example

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\newcommand{\newthreadShift}[4][gray!30]{
  \newinst[#4]{#2}{#3}
  \stepcounter{threadnum}
  \node[below of=inst\theinstnum,node distance=0.8cm] (thread\thethreadnum) {};
  \tikzstyle{threadcolor\thethreadnum}=[fill=#1]
  \tikzstyle{instcolor#2}=[fill=#1]
}

\begin{sequencediagram}
    \centering
    \newthread{A}{Alice}
    \newthreadShift{B}{Bob}{3cm}
    
    \begin{messcall}{A}{$C, Id$}{B}{}
    \end{messcall}
    
        \begin{messcall}{B}{$C, Id$}{A}{}
   \end{messcall}
    
\end{sequencediagram}
```

Which gives the below diagram:

[image]

How can I add a label to the diagram (i.e Diagram 1) before my section V.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could take a look `subcaption` or `subfig` package. And this posts may also help (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645842/how-to-create-subfigures-add-overarching-legend-delete-1000-separator-and-add/645845#645845).  If you wanna solve a particular problem, you should provide MWE that everybody can compile it directly.

Comment: a label (text or an image) can be labeled as content of a TikZ's `node`. It is better to add a minimal working example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the question on a hurry on my phone. I've added an example now.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, but you may liked:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, many]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes
            }
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 55mm,
            > = Straight Barb,
    ms/.style = {minimum size=7mm},
    ts/.style = {transform canvas={yshift=#1}},
     N/.style = {draw, fill=gray, inner sep=0pt,
                 minimum height=22mm, minimum width=2mm,
                 node contents={},
                },
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small, 
                            text=black, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node (s)   [alice,ms]              {Alice};
\node (r)   [bob,  ms,right=of s]   {Bob};
%
\node (L) [N, below right=2mm of s.north east] (L);
\node (R) [N, below  left=2mm of r.north west] (R);
    \draw[dotted]   (L.south) edge ++ (0,-0.5)
                    (R.south) edge ++ (0,-0.5);

\draw [->,ts= 5ex] (L) edge["{$C,Id$}"] (R);
\draw [<-,ts= 2ex] (L) edge["{$C,Id$}"] (R);
\draw [->,ultra thick, gray,
        ts=-2ex] (L) edge["data?"]    (R);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]